# What do I misunderstand about import in ES6?

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, es6-modules

I've done very simple markdown previewer using mark library in React. At first I did it by adding scripts to my Index.html in the

```
<body>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@latest/dist/react.js">
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@latest/dist/react-dom.js">
    <script src="https://npmcdn.com/babel-core@5.8.38/browser.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/marked/0.3.6/marked.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/babel" src="script.js" ></script>
</body>
```

Everything worked fine, but when I removed strings react.js and  react-dom.js, and added them to the script.js as below, I saw an error in console:
[image: console error]

```
import React from "react.min"
import ReactDOM from "react-dom.min"
class Input extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        _text: "",
    };
}

handleChange(e) {
    this.setState({
        _text: marked(e.target.value)
    });
}

createMarkup() {
    let outPutVal = this.state._text ? this.state._text : this.state._init;
    return {
        __html: outPutVal
    };
}

render() {
    return (<form className="headDiv">
            <textarea onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)}
                      placeholder="Remember, be nice!"
                      id="inputText" rows="25" cols="100">{this.state._text}</textarea>
        <output id="outputText" dangerouslySetInnerHTML={this.createMarkup()} />
    </form>);
 }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Input/>, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Comment: Have you installed React using npm?

Comment: @MarkWilliams no I just add react js files to the working directory

Comment: You'll need to install React with a package manager like npm - or use a starter project - see my response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using JS modules, Babel only handles the translation of `import` statements into CommonJS `require` calls - you still need a module loader of some kind to actually handle linking them all up.

Some examples of tools you could use for this are:

- [Webpack](https://webpack.github.io)
- [Browserify](http://browserify.org/)
- [SystemJS](https://github.com/systemjs/systemjs)
- [JSPM](http://jspm.io/)

That said, since you have the libraries included as script tags in your page, just removing the imports entirely would probably fix your issue -  that approach really doesn't scale well though, so I encourage you to look into the above tools!

Comment: I 've read a little about Webpack and etc a , but I thought I just could do without them in such a small project. My mistake was in considering  that "import" in JS imports files automatically without any additional tools

Comment: @TarasYaremkiv I'd definitely recommend using [create-react-app](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app) to set up your projects if you're just starting out - it'll handle all this kind of stuff for you :)

Comment: Note from the future: 'Recently Safari 10.1 (Safari Beta), Firefox 54 (Nighly) and Edge 15 (next EDGE version) shipped the native implementation out of the box or behind a flag, so the time we can use this without module bundlers is coming.' ;)

Answer (score 1):

After installing with npm, you'd normally just import as follows (no .min):

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
```

You might want to consider a boilerplate like create-react-app - brilliant for getting started with an environment to focus on learning react.

[create-react-app](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app)

Answer (score 1):

In order to use `import` within your `JSX code` you need to use either `webpack` or `browserify` . Also you need to install these modules using npm before importing them

In order to install them run

```
npm install -S react-dom
npm install -S react
```

You can later import them as

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
```

[Here](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2015/08/setting-up-react-for-es6-with-webpack-and-babel-2.html) is an easy tutorial that you can follow to set up your react code with webpack